# New abusers asking new abuser questions

Tags: feature-request

At the risk of incurring the wrath of the bad-question apologists, we need 
somewhere in which new users can ask bad questions without being downvoted for not following the accepted SO rules of good questions.

Yes I get that this would be a forum of just writing code for newbies,rather 
than  actual valuable  assistance, an such an idea has been proposed before, 
but within SO, and foundered because nobody would want to go there to answer 
questions and provide tuition.. but wait! There is a good supply of people 
just waiting to provide such rote code-generation and endlessly provide 
instruction on how to wite loops:  all those who post on SO meta about 
'hostile, unhelpful elites who should be teaching, not mob-downvoting'.

WE ALL BEGAN WITH BEGINNERS QUESTIONS. So down vote this if you will - I don't care, but let me suggest an alternative to simply crushing new programmers - set up a newbie tuition site, completely divorced from SO, in which those of us who write meta-rants about 'hostile and elitist trolls who just downvote and do not teach' can can help those who are just beginning to learn who to program. Lets call this site 'AAOR', for now, ('Ask Any Old Rubbish').

Such an external site would provide a perfect dumping gro... alternative, more fitting, place for those who can not and/or will not do any work for themselves.  This includes both those who post apalling bad questions by SO 
standards, and also those who rant on SO meta about the 'hostile and 
unconstructive' way that such posters are handled, but suggest 'solutions' that involve effort by other people, never volunteering themselves.

A meta script, or 'DUMP' button, could add the ranters as as members of the new AAOR site, and they could be given the option to move their entire SO account, rep and all, to AAOR.

No more 'gimme teh codez', no more walls of untested, undebugged code with 
'does not work' and, most important no more 'hostile. elitist' meta posters.

They both get flushed down into AAOR.  WIN-WIN!

I am not a teacher, but want to help others learn and will provide some 
assistance if I'm reasonably sure I'm not being abused for homework/competitions etc. I hate that budding students of this art are
dissuaded from asking question just because the majority deem that their
questions do not fit the paradigm of SO, so provide them, and their kind and 
considerate friends who indicate that they want to wast... spend their time 
teaching newbs, somewhere to enlessly discuss 'i++ + ++i' UB without bothering with the SO that they don't seem to want to pariticipate in.

I'm tired of seeing new SO contributors abused simply 'cos they did not know 
how to handle the thousands of posters who have no interest in future SO 
users, being taught or doing any work at all beyond the absolute minimum to 
get some drone to answer their assignment question.

Downvote this post if you will, but ask yourself -where were all the good 
teachers when you were learning and try to see beyond the prism of what you 
know to the world of the new programmer. Lets instigate a new-user site in 
which newbie programmers have a forum for assistance rather than critism, but NOT in SO.

I am not a newbie, but I am proud of my stance against the continual abuse of skilled and experienced engineers who are willing to contribute a bit of spare time. Downvote me if you will - but first think of the next generation of SO contributors; wouldn't you like to avoid pissing them off by wasting their time?

Comment: Satire is golden :-) ...

Comment: So you just want to create a garbage area, where everything is allowed. Besides that I think that this won't work at all, what do people do when they see there are far more people on SO? They will just get their garbage and post it on SO in hope to get more response than in the garbage area.

Comment: There's already such site: reddit.com I think most of these people gather there anyway already.

Comment: Would you, for example, migrate this [write code for me](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35956513/2564301) question over there?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a (new) site for professional and enthusiast programmers and leave SO as is?

Comment: Since you're the one who first came to us with this great idea, I propose that we make you moderator of the new AAOR site!

Comment: @CodyGray Considering AAOR's mandate, that shouldn't be too taxing, taking at most 0 seconds per year...

Comment: @dedup Needy users are needy. Moderation isn't all about content. Martin will love it, getting to help all of these people!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker _"I am not sure if this is actually serious?"_ It's [plain satire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318874/new-users-asking-new-user-questions), and good one.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå FOTFLOL...... :)

Comment: @RadLexus Oh yes, absolutely for sure.  I would try to ensure that eggmatters and gavgrif get an 'urgent tuition required now' link in their inbox.

Comment: This feature seems outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is all fine and good, but... why this have to be in Stack Overflow? Why we need to change to cater others in our house?

Comment: @Braiam Because apparently the tens of thousands of other sites on the internet with no quality standards aren't an option for the types of people that like to come to SO and complain about the fact that it has quality standards.  It's not enough to have a place where they can ask any question they want, no matter how terrible, it's important that *nobody* be allowed to have a place to ask questions where quality is enforced.  And their needs outweigh everyone else's; that's just how it is.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I can taste the satire and it's actually surprisingly good, but it doesn't go down smooth.

Comment: The satire is dripping from this post ;)