# Is it OK to be so harsh to a newbie's first question that is not that bad?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently (yesterday) saw this question:

- *[Detecting patterns in an ECG waves](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35972447/2521214)*

With very **interesting problem** (non-duplicate, trivial syntax, or quiz question). It looks like it is the first question of this user here (member only for four days now).

Yes, the question has its wrongs like **very poor English** (mine is not good, but that was even worse) and formatting so I edited it as much as I could without the additional data. I also comment him (as usual) with request for additional data and my concerns for robustness.

Today I had a look if he added new information and saw the question got ***10*** down-votes and got **on hold** with reason `unclear what you are asking ...` Which is not true in my opinion. Yes, the question may sound like a **code request** (and reviewers choose any other close option), but I suspect this is only due to the poor English skills and low/none experience on this site (try to read the [unedited version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35972447/1)).

Anyway I saw much worse questions out here that got even positive score...

**So my question is: How do I handle such cases properly?**

- I am aware of [Is it OK to downvote or close new users' first questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268006/2521214)

But in this case the question is salvageable (even now it contains enough data for non-robust solution). And looks like it got closed even before the user could respond.

**PS.**

I do not have a problem with **downvoting**, But ***-10*** votes per day? And closing without any comment are in my opinion too much without any communication with the user. It is not that the question is silent for weeks... as it was asked yesterday.

Comment: What do you expect?. It is a *give me the codez* question

Comment: @CodyGray I agree but this question is not unclear ....

Comment: There isn't a single question in that post, so it *is* unclear what they're asking

Comment: You're right, it is very clear that he wants someone to do his work for him. That is not, however, a question. I'm not sure why you are going out of your way to facilitate that. If you think it should be re-opened, you may cast a vote.

Comment: @CodyGray - I think that he already has done that

Comment: I did not got the impression it is a code request even if it looks like it (that is my feeling). But if it is I will act accordingly. I usually wait for user response on newbies. The ones with poor english usually do not even know how to formulate question in english. On non newbies it is easy just to see some of their posts and then is all clear.

Comment: I disagree. It's a lazy and bad question that deserves a down vote. My entire career I've worked in an international environment where people speak different languages. Hence I am very tolerant of poor English and would never down vote for that reason. Yet, lazy people are just lazy people regardless of language ... and that shows.

Comment: It should be a bit obvious that it is not a question, it is a task.  Without any clue where an answer needs to start, SO does get misused for "I need to hire a programmer" questions.  If the OP really wants to do it himself then a (better) question at dsp.stackexchange.com needs to be first

Comment: I looked at this for a while.  It looks like an interesting problem, in there somewhere, but in the end I downvoted it as 'gimme teh codez' and close voted as too broad, which it is.  Apart from that, I would not be happy attempting any kind of analysis of such data without the backup of in-depth medical knowledge:(

Comment: If offered a contract with a bio-electronics company, I would be all over such a problem:)  On SO, for free, with no backup, no shielding, no way.

Comment: You've stated right in this meta question that you needed additional information to answer the question, and needed the OP to respond to clarifying questions before you could do anything more.  That's the *definition* of "unclear what you're asking".  The question doesn't contain enough information to be answered, so it needs to be closed until it can be edited to clarify the information that's missing.  You should have cast a close vote yourself, given that *you* have asserted that the question doesn't contain enough information to be answered.

Comment: Anyway, if it's off-line analysis of boring data tables, why use C?  May as well use some nasty, interpreted gunge instead.

Comment: You all know I meant 'Perl' there, yes?

Comment: @MartinJames heh :) was afraid of Excel

Comment: @Spektre that did occur to me - you could then use the graphing functionality to create the ECG graph in quack-readable form.

Answer (score 18):

> interesting problem [...] the question is salvageable [...] *"unclear what you are asking"* is not true in my opinion

Not every interesting problem makes for a good question. The question currently states, paraphrased:

> Here's a bunch of data points and a graph plotted of those points, how do I detect [arbitrary points in graph] using C?

That is, by definition, "unclear what you're asking". It is not clear to the answerers with **what exact part of the problem the OP needs help**. As currently stated, all they may be looking for is someone who writes the entire program for them, which is not what Stack Overflow exists for, whoever may make you think differently.

If the OP linked some relevant algorithms, and some example criteria (like *"How can I determine `P` differently from `T` by measuring the flux length"* or whatever), it might be improved somewhat. Currently, it's too broad/unclear/off-topic anyway.

Comment: +1 nice answer I did not look at it in this way

Comment: usual code request question usually do not include relevant data like the one question that is why I tend to think it is not a code request but your statements hold even in this case btw I would highlight with bold the `Not every interesting problem makes for a good question`  statement of yours

Comment: A code request with additional data or examples doesn't _not_ make it a code request. The term "code request" is vague anyway, almost any answer contains some form of code. "Unclear" is clear enough: it is unclear with which part specifically they need help.

Comment: yes but the "code requesters" usually do not include relevant data because they do not know what that is (I was teaching in past so have some experience with this).  So I am still not fully convinced without feedback of the user. But You convinced me about the unclear reason

Answer (score 10):

> Yes the question may sound like code request

Correction. The question **is a code request**.

> Today I had a look if he added new info and saw question got 10
>   down-votes and got on hold with reason unclear what you are asking ...
>   Which is not true in my opinion. Yes the question may sound like code
>   request (and reviewers choose any other close option) but I suspect
>   this is only due to the poor English skills and low/none experience on
>   this site (try to read the unedited version).

This question serves as a very good example for *how not to ask a question*. Let us look at it for a moment (not trying to belittle anyone) and see what the [help center says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Things that are really important for a good question

> 1. Introduce the problem <strike>before you post any code</strike>

He wants to detect patterns. But how?, which library does he want to use?, are there any constraints?. Nope, no info at all.

> 2. Help others reproduce the problem

How can others reproduce this?

> 3. Post the question and respond to feedback

I don't see this either.

Other things that affect how quickly a question is DVed / closed :

> 1. Questions asking for code.
> 2. OP just dumping input and expected output.
> 3. OP being *arrogant*, including incorrect tags to get more attention (the list goes on and on)

If a question is closed as *unclear*, it should be clear to the OP that people are not able to understand the question.

Yes, sometimes OP's poor communication skills do lead to questions being closed, but they can be reopened if edited properly (assuming other things are fine).

I don't see how the question you are referring to can have an *accurate answer*.

Comment: A good question, asked mostly in, say, Portuguese or Spanish, is often actually good fun to unravel and answer:)

Answer (score -30):

Being harsh to the newbies, is like scolding a child, if he/she asks a knowledgeable and genuine question but very vaguely.

This should be met by the Stack Overflow senior members with a real concern for knowledge, not just downvoting the question to get rid of the newbie.

Most questions asked on Stack Overflow are genuine and of real interest, but the OP especially newbie does not have experience asking questions on Stack Overflow. So, he/she does its best to ask, but is heart-broken by the downvotes army's rage.

Such questions must dealt with comments, before getting harshly on the OP with a swarm of downvotes.

Comment: Equating a downvote to kicking a child in the face is utterly nonsensical. Your argument goes off the rails as soon as it gets started.

Comment: Being kind to newbies and encouraging half-assed questions _"because they don't know better"_ makes for terrible communities. This site does not exist to answer everyobdy's question however poorly phrased, it exists to answer every answerable programming question. A considerable difference.

Comment: A helpful community is never a terrible community.

Comment: This site existed in the first place because people needed help and they got it better here. But, for a while now, people are getting downvotes instead of getting knowledge on SO.

I know my fellow don't ask their problems on SO just because of the fear of getting downvoted and insulted.

Comment: At what point would you consider someone *not* a "newbie"? The users name/rep is one of the last things I look at and it *never* has any influence on my up/down voting decision. All you'd be doing is delaying the inevitable when someone finally reaches your not-a-newbie barrier

Comment: _"This site existed in the first place because people needed help"_ - no, you may want to [read up on SO's history](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/). _"A helpful community is never a terrible community"_ - a community that allows any crap to be posted just to be helpful to everyone will go down eventually.

Comment: 'Most questions asked on SO are genuine and of real interest' - must be on different tags to those I normally frequent.  Most of them I see are dups, trivia, LMGTFY and the like :(

Comment: 'downvotes army's Rage', 'Such questions must dealt with comments' right, OK, then..

Comment: Your name goes on the list of AAOR contributors.  Clear all your appointments for the forseeable future, because you are going to be working flat-out 24/7 until you drop: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318883/new-abusers-asking-new-abuser-questions

Comment: 'Such questions must dealt with comments, [from other people who will do the actual work. not me], before getting harshly on the OP with swarm of downvotes.'

Comment: 'professional end enthusiast programmers' are not children.  Children should not be asking questions on SO.

Comment: I mean, FFS, I just popped onto the C tag and this appeared; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012196/write-the-program-in-c-and-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012829/why-does-while-loop-in-c-terminates-abrubptly

Comment: We dont care about users,  but good QA. Downvotes are our way of quality control. Don't want to get any? Don't post trash and you won't.

Comment: @Magisch I disagree on a post being trash most of time. If we encourage the OP to ask the question in more comprehensible way, it might become piece of knowledge that never existed before on SO.

Comment: @RahulParashar Or more effectively, we downvote OP and link him the help center. If he fails to get it in time, he will be autobanned shortly. I don't have time or patience for newbies who don't either.

Comment: yes linking to help center and constructive commenting is all I ask from "Experts" on SO. Collaboration is better than competition.

Comment: @RahulParashar Competition? We don't downvote and close-vote for competition. While constructive commenting is definitely suggested and recommended, you can't expect EVERY newbie to get his hand held while he reads the doc he should've read before posting. It's just not scalable with the numbers we're currently dealing with.

Comment: Related: Some answers to *[Why do some people hate Stack Overflow?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow)*.